# Use of next() method in Use() method in .net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, request-pipeline

What happens if I don't call next() method or next.Invoke() in a Use() method in the request pipeline, will it call the next middleware component or not?

Comment: Nope, the request will progress no further. Fairly useful if you want to intercept requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0), emphasis mine:

> Chain multiple request delegates together with Use. The next parameter represents the next delegate in the pipeline. **You can short-circuit the pipeline by not calling the next parameter**.

And:

> When a delegate doesn't pass a request to the next delegate, it's called short-circuiting the request pipeline. Short-circuiting is often desirable because it avoids unnecessary work. For example, Static File Middleware can act as a terminal middleware by processing a request for a static file and short-circuiting the rest of the pipeline.

So if you don't invoke the next item, the pipeline will stop there.